# Не могу понять как описать цикл

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как будет выглядеть цикл на такую программу? Откуда в конце в знаменателе второе i появляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решение задачи заключается именно в этом: понять

Comment: А почему тогда тег С++?

Comment: @Vladimir Ch, ну а  куда вы предложите?

Answer (score 1):

В комментарий картинку не вставить... Поэтому вынужден тут.

Запишем вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь понятно, какой цикл нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Обеспечим наглядность, чтоб не было вопросов типа: "а почему C++?..."

```
int main()
{  
    const int n{9};
    vector<double> f(n + 1);
    double sum(0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {            
        cout <<"f" <<i <<" = ";
        for (int j = 1; j <= i + 1; ++j) {
            sum += (double)1 / (i * i + j);
            cout << 1 << "/(" << i <<'*' << i <<'+'<<j <<')' ;
            if(!(j%5)) cout << "\n\t";
            if (j != i + 1)
                cout << " + " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
        f[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

все выводы чистая формальность

Comment: `int sum{};` -- а что это? :)

Comment: Это С++ выражение:  sum инициализируется значением по умолчанию, т.е.  нулем

Comment: `sum += 1 / (i * i + j);` *только не это, шеф! только не это! (с)* `double sum; ... sum += 1 .0/ (i * i + j);` - и обнулять `sum` в первом цикле...

Comment: @Harry,  да, конечно вы правы, это называется поспешишь, людей насмешишь... Сейчас исправлю. спасибо! Просто я сначала написал код только для знаменателья, а потом добавил 1 /   это конечно моя ошибка

Comment: хотя и теперь есть ошибка